# Access Listview currentIndex from Delegate

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qqmlcomponent

I have a QML `ListView` where the delegate loads it's component from another file. When clicking on an delegate item, I want to update `ListView`. `CurrentIndex` and `highlight` the selected item.

It works, when I explicitly set the `id` of the `ListView`. However since I want to use the delegate's `Component` also for other `ListView`s, I'm stuggeling to find a generic way how to access `ListView.currentIndex` from within a delegate `Component`.

Here is the Code:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    ListModel {
        id: contactsModel
        ListElement {
            name: "Bill Smith"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "John Brown"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "Sam Wise"
        }
    }

    ListView{
        id: contactsView
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        orientation: Qt.Vertical
        spacing: 10
        model: contactsModel
        delegate: Contact{}
    }
}
```

**Contact.qml** (Component used by delegate)

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Component{
    id: contact
    Rectangle{
        width: 200
        height: 50
        color: ListView.isCurrentItem ? "#003366" : "#585858"
        border.color: "gray"
        border.width: 1

        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                ListView.currentIndex = index; // <---- does not work
                //  contactsView.currentIndex = index; // <---- Works
            }
        }

        Text{
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            color: "white"
            text: name
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- You need to qualify `ListView`'s attached properties with the name of the item from which they're accessed.
- The `currentIndex` property is [a property of the `ListView` item type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#currentIndex-prop), not the [attached property object](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#properties).

To fix them both, first change this:

```
ListView.currentIndex = index;
```

to this:

```
delegate.ListView.view.currentIndex = index;
```

And then give your delegate an `id`:

```
Component {
    id: contact

    Rectangle {
        id: delegate
    // ...
}
```

This is demonstrated (in part) by the [Example Usage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#example-usage) section of the documentation:

> ListView attaches a number of properties to the root item of the delegate, for example ListView:isCurrentItem. In the following example, the root delegate item can access this attached property directly as ListView.isCurrentItem, while the child contactInfo object must refer to this property as wrapper.ListView.isCurrentItem.

Answer (score 4):

Use attached property [`ListView.view`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#view-attached-prop):

> This attached property holds the view that manages this delegate
>   instance

**Small example:**

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Window {
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Component {
        id: listDelegate
        Rectangle {
            height: 30
            width: parent.width
            color:  ListView.isCurrentItem ? "orange" : "white"
            property var view: ListView.view
            property int itemIndex: index
            Text { anchors.centerIn: parent; text: name }
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    view.currentIndex = itemIndex;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        ListView {
            Layout.minimumWidth: parent.width / 2
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            model: ListModel {
                ListElement {name: "item1.1"}
                ListElement {name: "item1.2"}
                ListElement {name: "item1.3"}
            }
            delegate: listDelegate
        }
        ListView {
            Layout.minimumWidth: parent.width / 2
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            model: ListModel {
                ListElement {name: "item2.1"}
                ListElement {name: "item2.2"}
                ListElement {name: "item2.3"}
            }
            delegate: listDelegate
        }
    }
}
```